# Apache BeanUtils.copyProperties slow access for the first time

Tags: java

When I run a springboot project in idea with main function, it does'not slow for the first time.

While when I run then project in cmd (java -jar demo.war), it slows for the first time (about 600ms) and second time about 10ms.

What could be a possible reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

Project description
gradle6.6 springboot2.3.0RELEASE

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
}
```

1.by debug the method,finally locate in Class ClassFinder'method findClass,here is

```
try {
            ClassLoader var1 = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            if (var1 == null) {
                var1 = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            }

            if (var1 != null) {
                return Class.forName(var0, false, var1);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException var2) {
        } catch (SecurityException var3) {
        }
```

var1 is TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader which is slow to load class

2.i think the problem is the classloader,then i change the Servlet container

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
        exclude group:'org.springframework.boot',module:  'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    implementation 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow'
}
```

3.debug the method findClass i find the var1 is LauchedURLClassLoader which is fast
to load class.